# Looping filter copy paste over multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large file that comes in as dirty data and needs to be cleaned up.  Some of the data is blended so an advanced filter is needed to show only "Dog" then copy visible cells only (range of columns), paste those to a specified column (on the first visible blank cell below header) clear the filter and repeat on the next column.  These columns that need to be searched for "Dog" occur every 7 columns.  i.e., A1, H1, O1, etc.  I have this below script that I've been working with to try to get the result I'm looking for.

2 problems:
1) when it performs the filter for column 410 it should be copying just visible cells, but after it pastes it's actually including hidden cells when the whole table is unfiltered.
2) If this script was doing what was expected, Since this action needs to be performed on 50 columns, using select this many times will be extremely slow.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

```
Sub CopyPaste()

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$API$65536").AutoFilter Field:=403, Criteria1:= _
    "=*Dog*", Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("OM2:ABP65536").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Cut

    Dim Rng As Variant

    Range("ABQ1").Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("clean_report").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData 
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$API$65536").AutoFilter Field:=410, Criteria1:= _
    "=*Dog*", Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("OT2:ABP65536").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("ABQ1").Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("clean_report").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following code will help you achieve your desired result, it will loop through every 7 columns starting at A until your last Column with data, it will filter that given column with criteria "Dog", copy all visible cells and paste into another sheet, in the case below sheet result:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("clean_report")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim wsResult As Worksheet: Set wsResult = Sheets("result")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, i As Long, ResultRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
Lastcol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'get the last column with data on Row 1

For i = 1 To Lastcol Step 7 'go through columns A then H in 7 column intervals
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, Lastcol)).AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="*Dog*", Operator:=xlAnd
    'filter by "Dog"
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, Lastcol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    'copy all visible cells from A2 to LastRow on LastCol
    ResultRow = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'find next free row on result sheet
    wsResult.Range("A" & ResultRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    'paste in free row
    ws.ShowAllData
    'remove filter for next iteration of loop
Next i
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

As per your comment, please find the updated version below, this will loop from column A to OI (in 7 column intervals) and filter for the word "Dog" and paste the visible cells to the next available empty row on Column PB:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("clean_report")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim wsResult As Worksheet: Set wsResult = Sheets("result")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

For i = 1 To 399 Step 7 'go through columns A to OI in 7 column intervals
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, 402)).AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="*Dog*", Operator:=xlAnd
    'filter by "Dog"
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, 402)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    'copy all visible cells from A2 to LastRow on LastCol
    ResultRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "PB").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'find next free row on result sheet
    ws.Range("PB" & ResultRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    'paste in free row
    ws.ShowAllData
    'remove filter for next iteration of loop
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Xabier,
Thank you for your reply.  I gave the code a try but it isn't quite achieving what I'm looking for.  Instead of it pasting to a new sheet, I'm hoping to have it paste into the same sheet 'clean_report' in a set column let's say column 'PB' for example.   But, I only want it to paste into the visible cells.  That way the rows are still matched up in order.  The data filter starts at column OM so the data  needs to be in corresponding row as A - OL.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Amanda, I've updated my answer to reflect your comments, please could you also mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you!  I just have to make a couple additions but this got me to what I needed.